# PayPal Express Checkout onAuthorize method is enough to confirm the payment?

Tags: paypal

I'm implementing a PayPal Checkout Server Integration, and I would like to know if is secure to mark the order as paid when onAuthorize method is fired.

I would like to know too if is needs to implement the webhook to verify the payment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on "classic" which is marked deprecated from Jan 17

I have the same question. The calls show in the Sandbox API Call History but I cannot see any money flowing. The same for my live account. I have the gut feeling that the transaction needs to be captured after its authorization.

To capture the payment, issue a DoCapture request using the returned Authorization ID.
Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_authorize_and_capture/#required-code-changes-for-authorization-and-capture

UPDATE: I wasn't using classic after all but the new Client Side Rest: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

It is close to classic, I only needed to add ...

```
return actions.payment.execute();
```

Then the actual transfer takes place.